# Cleaning a Microsoft Natural Ergonomic 4000 keyboard

Tags: keyboard, cleaning

This is one of the best keyboards for programmers. I read an article saying that running a keyboard through the dishwasher would clean it, but I'm unsure about a keyboard like this which has a faux leather wrist guard. Any suggestions?

Comment: - take screwdriver
- disassemble
- clean
- assemble - done

Comment: pop the keys off and wash in a large bowl of warm soapy water

Comment: @shufler I tried this today, it took forever.  Now when I plugged it back in the backspace key does it's job, but it also enters a bunch of j's.  

I'm guessing maybe I need to let it dry out a little longer.  (Though I though they keys were dry).

Comment: If it is really bad and you got a few bucks, I would personaly just order a new one and keep the other as a backup. haha

Comment: I had Microsoft Natural Elite and keys were easily removable. I've tried it in this MS Natural Elite 4000 but the force needed to remove keys is substantial so I'm afraid of breaking it. Can the keys really be removed without disassembling keyboard?

Comment: Dishwasher powder contains a lot of salt, which would make the electronics short circuit even after it has dried out.  Also, it would take months for the water to dry out between in the membrane in a keyboard like that.  Putting a dishwasher in a dishwasher is a terrible idea.

Comment: Here is a video (poor quality) of someone disassembling the keyboard:
http://youtu.be/IZhCzOOhX2E

Comment: @paranoid That last part... I can't tell if it's a typo or a joke. Anyways, what if you took it apart before putting it in? Like unscrewing it and separating the case, membrane, etc.

Comment: @Troggy not all of is have money to spare. Some of is are just high schoolers without a job.

Comment: [Coding Horror: Cleaning Your Display and Keyboard](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/05/cleaning-your-display-and-keyboard.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just put my Ergonomic 4000 keyboard through the dishwasher and I'm happy to report it works perfectly.

Here's what I recommend:

- Use the top rack
- Face the keys downward
- Use little/no soap
- Remove before drying cycle

After the washing, I shook it out as best as possible and then let it sit in a hot room for three days. After plugging it back in, everything worked great.

I did have a bit of white soap residue on the palm rest that I was easily able to remove with a wet sponge.

Comment: Do not forget to remove the electronics first, otherwise they may corrode. If you really like your keyboard, don't take that chance with it.

Comment: @Broam to be fair, it's not much of a chance to take... you can just buy another one for 25-55 bucks depending on sales.

Comment: I ordered another for $20 from Dell just in case this didn't work. I didn't even take the electronics out this time. If I get three years out of a keyboard, I'm happy with it. This washing bought me at least a year.

Comment: To add another datapoint: I also just put my MS 4000 keyboard upside down on the top rack of the dishwasher. Loose detergent was not available, so I used a few drops of dish soap. I let it sit standing on end over the weekend. The dishwasher used some amount of heat that was not selectable, that caused the already worn palmrest to wrinkle up a bit more than before. The unworn parts are unaffected. Otherwise the keyboard is clean and works fine.

Comment: Another data point: I killed Ergo 4000 by spilling a little pure water on it. It was powered, though.

Comment: I did it with a quite old MS E 4000. It worked fine even that I'm not a pro with tools and things like that. The dishwasher (**without** hot dryer programm!) worked also for the none electronic parts (the upper side of the case and the keycaps). Looks nice. But I have to say that the functionality is the same. The keys are still spongy. In my case I would say cleaning didn't helped. The spongy feeling comes from the age of the device not from the dirt in it. Most of the dirt was under the keys. Maybe no need to open the whole case. Just pop up the keys and clean under them.

Answer (score 25):

Here's a guide that I found useful:

- Unplug it from the computer. While this might seem obvious, some people might go commando and use the thing while in the process of cleaning it. You've been warned. ;-)
- Remove (no exaggeration) 21 screws from the underside.
- Place right side up and wiggle off the faux-leather wrist rests.
- Remove a screw from under each of the newly-removed wrist rests.
- Find a small flathead screwdriver (or some other flat prying object), slide under the front edge of the space bar and gently give it a twist. The spacebar should pop right out. Set it aside.
- Remove two silver screws and then remove the top cover. Note that this will require some wiggling becase there are a few plastic catches sort-of holding it in place, such as in front below the F-Lock light.
- If your keyboard is anything like mine was, you'll need to be able to clean under what's left, so remove 4 more screws under where the Back and Forward buttons normally are along with the metal bar they hold down.
- Remove the silicone overlays.

When placing the space bar back, remember to start with metal spring  inside the spacebar.

From:
http://darkwyrm-haiku.blogspot.com/2008/07/cleaning-microsoft-ergo-natural.html

Comment: Thank you so much for this. **The spacebar should pop right out**, this was illuminating and allowed for the safe removal of the top portion of the keyboard.

Answer (score 4):

Putting an electronic keyboard, especially this one, through a dishwasher is not a good idea, unless you want to sell more keyboards.
The inside of the keyboard is made up of three plastic layers sandwiched together. The top and bottom layers have metal wires laid out like a printed circuit board. The middle layer is an insulator, but with holes that line up with each of the keys on the keyboard. Metal traces on the top and bottom of each hole are separated by air in the thickness of the middle layer of plastic.
When a key is not pressed, these metal traces do not touch one another. When a key is pressed, the top layer is pressed down into the hole until the metal trace at the top touches the metal trace at the bottom and completes the circuit. When you let up on the key, the plastic returns to its original position with the metal traces not touching.

Now, what happens when you introduce water? The top and bottom layers of plastic do not have any exposed holes near these switches, so water can't enter there.  However, the Achilles heal is the edge of the plastic and the alignment holes that go through all 3 layers.  When a liquid hits an edge or one of these through-holes, the layers of plastic act like a capillary, and draw the liquid between the layers.  Everything is still okay...until the liquid finds its way to one of the switch contacts. The liquid can short out a switch contact and it will act as if the key is permanently pressed.  Other liquids, for example, the milk that my kids spilled on the keyboard, will wick into the plastic, turn to cheese, and could act as an insulator or a conductor.

I tried taking the keyboard apart, peeling apart the 3 layers, which are not fastened to each other, cleaning, drying, and re-assembling. It still didn't work, so my kids are splitting the cost of a new keyboard.

Comment: "Sell more keyboards"? You mean "_buy_ more keyboards," right?

Comment: Or "help your local office supply or computer retail store sell more keyboards"?

Answer (score 3):

I have one and I just hold it upside down and use pressurized air along all the key edges.  Cleans out all the little human leavins :)

Unscrewing it though and getting under the keys would be your best method.

Comment: This doesn't work with dead skin, does it?

Answer (score 2):

I use rubbing alcohol and some cuetips on each key, it takes a while, but the results look pretty good.

As for the faux leather pad, I've just used general office cleaner, or windex.

It's not as nice as a dishwasher idea, but I'm terrified of washing a keyboard in the dishwasher.  I'd imagine people with hard water or other mineral additives might end up damaging their keyboards.

Answer (score 1):

Unless your keyboard was made in the 70s, its not a good idea.

In addition to what people suggested earlier

For very dirty conventional keyboards, i'd recommend a wipe with a damp cloth the get the surface dirt off, pop off the keytops (photographing it first if you can!), and putting it a delicates (steal one from the missus!) bag before putting JUST the keys in the washing machine for a quick, cold water cycle.

For between keys or places you can't scrub, or general dust removal, especially on non removable keytops . i tend to use something called cyberclean to clean between keyboards. Ars technica's review wasn't very positive, but the stuff works, just smush it on your keyboard and the crud stucks to it - a 9 dollar jar of the stuff lasts for 3-6 months for general keyboard cleaning, so its pretty worth it.